# How to animate textures in a 3d model?

Tags: libgdx, textures, bytebuffer

I wish to have a animated 3d texture in my LibGDX code but I am struggling to find out how to do it.

I assume how this "should" be done is either;

a) Directly accessing and modifying the texture on the model. (via a pixmap? ByteBuffer?)

or

b) Prerendering a big image containing all the frames (say, 20) and then moving the UV co-ordinates to create the illusion of the animation. (akin to ImageStrips in 2d/webdesign).

I did work out how I could completely replace the material eachtime, but that seems a much worse way of doing it. So if anyone could show the commands I need to do either a) or b) (or a similar optimal method) I would be great-fall.
Maths I am fine with. The intricacies of OpenGLES or GDX I am not :)

(The solution should at least work HTML/Android compiles, ideally everything)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the latest release it is very easy to play a 2d animation on a 3d surface. First make sure to get familiar with the 2d animation concept, as explained over here: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/2D-Animation. Then, instead of using a spritebatch, you can use the `TextureRegion` (which `Animation#getKeyFrame` returns) to set the material of the surface, as shown here: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/g3d/TextureRegion3DTest.java. So basically you would get in your render method:

```
attribute.set(animation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true));
```

Or if you want a more generic approach:

```
instance.getMaterial("<name of material>").get(TextureAttribute.class, TextureAttribute.Diffuse).set(animation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true));
```

Or, if there's only one material in the ModelInstance:

```
instance.materials.get(0).get(TextureAttribute.class, TextureAttribute.Diffuse).set(animation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true));
```

Comment: By newest you mean 1.4.1? Or some nightly something?
That method sure looks easy, but I don't seem to have a "Set" method on TextureAttribute.

Comment: TextureAttribute attribute = instance3.materials.get(0).get(TextureAttribute.class, TextureAttribute.Diffuse);

"attribute" will have no "set" method.

Comment: The latest release is 1.4.1, in which TextureAttribute#set(TextureRegion) exists. See: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/1.4.1/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/attributes/TextureAttribute.java#L122

Comment: Ah, Then I haven't updated right. As I thought I was on that.
My .gradle file says "gdxVersion = '1.4.1'" but maybe something else is wrong. Pretty new to Libgdx

Comment: didnt refresh Graddle >_<

Comment: Ok all working fine, that was pretty easy once I had that "set".
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the memory for it I would definetly choose b), it is easier on the processor. Also, you would only change a uniform's value. However, due to preprocessing it might take some time to open the application.

Get you uniform variable, where you compile your shaders, animationPos should be global.

```
Gluint animationPos = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "nameoftheuniform");
```

Your main loop should pass animationPos value to the shader:

```
Gluniform1i ( animationPos, curentAnimationIndex);
```

Add this your fragment shader variables:

```
uniform int animationPos;
```

Fragment shader main:

```
float texCoordY = texCoord.y; //texture coordinates should be passed from vertex shader
float texCoordX = texCoord.x/20.0f; //we are dividing it with 20 since it is the amount of textures that we have and if we use it directly it would try to use all the texture. Whereas the texture stores at 20 different textures.

float textureIndex = 1.0f*animationPos/20.0f; //Pointer to the start of the animation texture.
gl_fragColor = texture2D ( yourTexture, vec2( textureIndex + texCoordX, texCoordY));
```

Above code assumes that you expanded your textures in the x direction, you can also try to expand it like a matrix, then you need to change the texCoord calculation part. Also that we are using 20 textures.

The option a) is more heavy on the processor and you will be changing the texture every time so it will use pci a bit more, but easier on memory. The question is more like a design decision, but I guess 20 images can be handled so go with option b).

Edit: Added code.